# asp.net mvc jquery dialog one-to-many data updates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, one-to-many

Here is the scenario. I have a view for creating orders.  The view has some header information to be captured like address of customer, delivery mode etc., There is also a grid to show the list of products that the customer has ordered.  When customer wants to add a product, I show the jquery dialog modal which will have the product information.  When I click save on the dialog, I run into few questions.

1. How do I pass the data back to main view and link the product `List<Product>` data and save it within the Order class?
2. Are there any better way of doing it?  I need the dialog modal instead of going back and forth to different pages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific requirements.

I do something very similar to what you describe.  My modal dialog makes an Ajax post back to a controller to update the entity it is editing and closes itself.

I then trigger another portion of the HTML to refresh via an Ajax call once the modal dialog closes (for example, if you are showing a list of things being edited).

Comment: What if I want to save my Order data only after clicking "Save" on my main view? Where do I store the data from partial view without going to controller?

Comment: In that case, the form used to update the record is still in the DOM.  Remember, your modal dialog is part of the same HTML page that your main view is part of.  You can use jQuery to trigger the form submit from a link/button on the main view.  Keep in mind, though, that if you edit a different record in the mean time, the original values will be replaced.  If you need to allow for multiple edits that are all submitted at once, the best thing I can think of is to have the modal dialog serialize the form data to a JavaScript array (one element per edit) and submit data from that array on save.